# Undefined variable error using function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a PHP code in which i pass a variable to a function.

My code is working file if i use HTML select tag

```
<span id="opinion">
            <select name="" id="" STYLE="width: 300px"  onchange="get_opinion(this.value)">
                <option value="">[--Select opinion------]</option>
            <?php 
            if(is_array($opinions) && !empty($opinions))
                {
                    foreach($opinions as $opinion)
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'.$opinion->ID.'"';
                        echo '>';
                        echo $opinion->name;
                        echo '</option>';

                    } 
                }                       

                 ?>
                 </select>
            </span>
```

But i want to display my data with Check Box,
 When i use Check box with that code i face error "Undefined Variable $opinions"

```
        <?php 
        if(is_array($opinions) && !empty($opinions))
            {
                foreach($opinions as $opinion)
                {

                    echo    '<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="'.$opinion->ID.'"> $opinion->name';
                } 
            }                       

             ?>

        </span>
```

**Update:**

i define that variable as

```
if(isset( $_REQUEST['fileType']))
{$file_type = $_REQUEST['fileType'];}
else {$file_type=0;}

if(isset($file_type) && $file_type!=0)
{
    $opinions = $cont->get_opinions($file_type); } } }
```

JavaScript

```
 function get_opinion_methodology(myid)
{
    var id = document.getElementById("file_methodology").value;
    alert(id);
$.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "test1.php",
        data: "fileType="+myid,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(msg){
        $("#opinion").html(msg);

        }
    });
}
```

Can you please help me to sort out my problem??

Comment: Where do you define that variable?

Comment: Where is that function & variable??

Comment: Are you trying to add `<input type="checkbox"...` to select element?

Comment: @Qirel i update my question

Comment: @AmitRajput i update my question

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 How i can use this?

Comment: which variable is undefined? alert(id);

Comment: @AmitRajput $opinions showing undefined

Comment: use a ``var_dump($opinions)`` before your if statement to verify that ``opionions`` has been initialized.  And before you defined what opinions actually is add ``$opionions = array()`` incase what ever your defining it too has no values.

Comment: @JoseRodrigues can you please put a line of code

Comment: Hi, your code  $opinions = $cont->get_opinions($file_type);  you are changed  to $opinions = $cont->get_opinions($file_type);  var_dump($opinions);

Comment: Next, You are execute it.

Comment: If var_dump is displayed, it is OK. But is not display, problem is if(isset($file_type) && $file_type!=0)

Comment: @jonghyonlee Its not working :(

Comment: your problem is  $_REQUEST['fileType']. you are changed to $_GET['fileType']

Comment: Of couse, All code $_REQUEST['fileType']. you will changed to $_GET['fileType'].

Comment: if you have problem, too. I need to detail your project.

Comment: If you change `if(is_array($opinions) && !empty($opinions))` to `if (!empty($opinions) && is_array($opinions)` - you'll get rid of the warning. But keep in mind that if the code doesn't work as intended, the problem is where you define `$opinions`. Seems like it's defined in a conditional-statement, meaning that it might not always be defined.

Comment: Thank you to All i solve my Problem With the help of @JoseRodrigues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `if(isset( $_REQUEST['fileType']))` add  `$opinions = array();`.
This will make sure you have opinions set even if file_type is not.

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my life

Answer (score 0):

Looks like typo in

```
echo    '<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="'.$opinion->ID.'"> $opinion->name';
```

Did you mean

```
echo    '<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="'.$opinion->ID.'">'.$opinion->name;
```

?

Comment: No its not my problem. My problem is that my Varibale $opinions is working well with HTML select tag. But this variable shown an error when i use it anyother tag